# Error after deploying rails app with nginx server

Tags: nginx, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am trying to depoly my railsapp through nginx and passenger server. after finishing the installation steps, i typed the domain name but it results the following error.
 404 found error

i followed this tutorial link to deploy my app
https://medium.com/@Alibaba_Cloud/how-to-deploy-ruby-on-rails-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04-9b435529a54b

please help .. I got stuck over here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your access/error logs to see what exactly is the issue.

They are generally located at /var/logs/nginx/ .